# How to keep Excel line graph from incorporating dates that are not in my range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have created a line graph based on dates and the values associated with those dates. However, it is inserting dates into a graph which I do not want. The dates run in chronological order, I only want the graph to display weekday dates whereas the graph actually inserts the weekend dates which are not in my data. Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: Ive not got enough rep to add any attachments yet!

Comment: Are you referring to labels on an axis or data points?

Comment: I have uploaded the image. the url is - http://imgur.com/FFAYTrD

Comment: I can understand your frustration; however, I have verified (by using a ruler and holding it up to my screen) that no data points relate to any of the weekend dates; the graph merely continues as normal.  Now, I know that this doesn't answer your question but it may well instil a little calm within you.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a scatter chart so the X axis is shown as chronologically correct.  The weekend dates are placeholders on the axis.  If you only want to show dates with data, use a line graph.  That will treat the dates as categories and just place them one after the other (make sure the data is pre-sorted because the dates will be interpreted as just labels with no numerical meaning).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options if you don't like Excel's default assumption that you want your line chart to show "in between" dates where you have no specific data points.

**Option 1 - show them as blanks**

If you add the weekend dates into your data, but leave the values blank, your chart does this. This might be what you're looking for.

[image]

**Option 2 - skip the dates like they don't exist**

Right-click the date axis. Select `Text axis` under `Axis Type:`. This will treat your dates as any other label - it could just as well be: "18/11/14","red","20/11/14","blue". It just treats it as text instead of a date, meaning your weekend dates aren't shown.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the option for "Axis Type" in my scatter plot options.. What can I do?

Chart: http://imgur.com/a/DlIcN

Options: http://imgur.com/a/b8SpP

Comment: Sorry only just seen this! Too late now, but for posterity - scatter plots by definition use numerical axes. A scatter plot with a text axis wouldn't be meaningful. One way you might work round this would be to create a date index number in a new column, that only counts 'working' days instead of calendar days, and use this as your axis instead of date. This would just increment from 1 to as many days as you want to display (although you wouldn't be able to see actual dates on the chart unless you add them as text boxes).